# php loop array to get total

Tags: php, arrays

I am having some difficulty looping through an array and calculating fields. Here is the array $iroom:

```
Array
(
   [num_rooms] => 2
   [adults] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 2
    )

   [prices] => Array
    (
        [0] => 44.5
        [1] => 44.5
    )

   [roomTotalPrice] => Array
    (
        [0] => 89
        [1] => 89
    )

   [price] => 178
)
```

I want to (adults*prices)+(adults*$asup)+(chidern*$csup)+$ssup and pu the answer into the roomTotalPrice. So far the outer forloop sets the roomTotalPrice price but I cannot get the inner loops to calculate the price. The $sup are extra supplement prices.

The code I got so far:

```
                        foreach($iroom['roomTotalPrice'] as &$irt){
                            foreach($iroom['adults'] as $ira){

                            }
                            $irt = ;
                        }
```

Comment: Can you show some math for the sample data you've provided? I'm not sure what you mean by multiplying arrays, or rather: I'm not sure how you want to go about it.

Comment: I want to multiple the adults by the prices and answer put into the roomTotalPrice field with some other small calculations. Eg $asup,$csup & are $10 so the first answer would be (2*44.5)+(2*10)+(1*10)+10 = 129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CODE WRAPPED IN FUNCTION, TO HANDLE NEW ARRAY FORMAT**

```
/*
  Note that this function may not be 100% correct. I notice you have removed
  the 'supp' key from the array, and that your current spec doesn't do anything
  with the 'price' key. I suspect you may want the line

    + ((isset($array['supp'])) ? $array['supp'] : 0);

  to read

    + ((isset($array['price'])) ? $array['price'] : 0);

*/    

function calculateTotalPrices ($array, $asup = 10, $csup = 10) {
  if (!is_array($array) || !isset($array['num_rooms']) || !$array['num_rooms']) return FALSE; // make sure data is valid
  for ($i = 0; $i < $array['num_rooms']; $i++) { // Loop num_rooms times
    $array['roomTotalPrice'][$i] =
      ((isset($array['adults'][$i],$array['prices'][$i])) ? ($array['adults'][$i] * $array['prices'][$i]) + ($array['adults'][$i] * $asup) : 0) // Calculate price for adults
      + ((isset($array['childern'][$i])) ? ($array['childern'][$i] * $csup) : 0) // Calculate price for children
      + ((isset($array['supp'])) ? $array['supp'] : 0); // Add the supplement
  }
  // Get a total price for adults + children + supplements for all rooms
  $array['grandTotal'] = array_sum($array['roomTotalPrice']);
  return $array;
}

$iroom = array (
  'num_rooms' => 2,
  'adults' => array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3
  ),
  'childern' => array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2
  ),
  'prices' => array (
    0 => 44.5,
    1 => 44.5
  ),
  'price' => 178,
);

print_r(calculateTotalPrices($iroom));
/* With the above array, outputs
Array
(
    [num_rooms] => 2
    [adults] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [childern] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [prices] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44.5
            [1] => 44.5
        )

    [price] => 178
    [roomTotalPrice] => Array
        (
            [0] => 119
            [1] => 183.5
        )

    [grandTotal] => 302.5
)
*/

print_r(calculateTotalPrices($iroom,20,25));
/* With your sample array, outputs
Array
(
    [num_rooms] => 2
    [adults] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [childern] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [prices] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44.5
            [1] => 44.5
        )

    [price] => 178
    [roomTotalPrice] => Array
        (
            [0] => 154
            [1] => 243.5
        )

    [grandTotal] => 397.5
)
*/
```

**CODE UPDATED WITH ADDITIONAL CHECKS**

```
foreach ($iroom as $k1 => $v1) { // Loop outer array
  if (is_array($v1)) { // Make sure element is an array
    foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) { // Loop inner array
      if (is_array($v2)) { // Make sure element is an array
        for ($i = 0; $i < $v2['num_rooms']; $i++) { // Loop num_rooms times
          $iroom[$k1][$k2]['roomTotalPrice'][$i] =
            ((isset($v2['adults'][$i],$v2['prices'][$i])) ? ($v2['adults'][$i] * $v2['prices'][$i]) + ($v2['adults'][$i] * $asup) : 0) // Calculate price for adults
            + ((isset($v2['childern'][$i])) ? ($v2['childern'][$i] * $csup) : 0) // Calculate price for children
            + $v2['supp']; // Add the supplement
        }
        // Get a total price for adults + children + supplements for all rooms
        $iroom[$k1][$k2]['grandTotal'] = array_sum($iroom[$k1][$k2]['roomTotalPrice']);
      }
    }
  }
}

print_r($iroom);
```

**EDIT**

Using the exact code above, feeding in the array above, and setting `$asup = $csup = 10;` at the top, I get no errors, and this output:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 2
                    [adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                            [1] => 3
                        )

                    [childern] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                        )

                    [prices] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 44.5
                            [1] => 44.5
                        )

                    [price] => 178
                    [supp] => 0
                    [roomTotalPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 119
                            [1] => 183.5
                        )

                    [grandTotal] => 302.5
                )

        )

)
```

Note that the first result comes out at 119, not 129 as you state in the comment above - this is because in your example array, `supp` is 0 and not 10, as you have used in your calculation.

I have also tested with more complex arrays (with more elements at the first and second levels) and it works fine.

I'm guessing if you are getting "invalid argument supplied for foreach" errors it's because in your actual array, you highest level has some non-array memebers. This can easily be overcome by changing

```
foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
```

to

```
if (is_array($v1)) foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I get Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: it seems the line foreach ($v1 as $k2=>$v2) {

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said that childern may not be in the array.

Comment: Also, not that it really matters, it should be spelled "children".

Comment: And remember that you need to set `$asup` and `$csup` *before* you run the code.

Comment: I am very sorry Dave. I showed the incorect array. The one I posted was overall array. Not the one to be sent for calculations. I have updated the array. It does not have the extra levels. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the help. I really appricate it. I have a much better understanding now. I all works great.